# Typescript/React TypeError: Cannot read property 'MaxEmailLength' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, static, frontend

I have a weird issue with typescript, so I have 2 static classes using each other and this doesn't work.

Class ValidationHelper (single file)

```
import { ValidationErrors } from '../dictionary/ValidationErrors';
    export class ValidationHelper {
    
        static readonly MaxEmailLength = 320;
    
        static IsEmailValid(email: string): ValidationResult {
            if (email.length < 0) {
                return new ValidationResult(false, ValidationErrors.MissingEmail);
            }
    
            if (email.length > this.MaxEmailLength) {
                return new ValidationResult(false, ValidationErrors.InvalidEmailLength);
            }
    
            return new ValidationResult(true);
        }
    }
```

Class ValidationErrors (single file)

```
import { ValidationHelper } from "../helpers/ValidationHelper";
    export class ValidationErrors {
    
        static readonly MissingEmail = "Please provide email.";
    
        static readonly InvalidEmailLength = `Email can't be longer than ${ValidationHelper.MaxEmailLength} characters.`;
    }
```

These classes are used in react component. Everything is built by webpack 4.44.1 into vendor.js runtime.js and file per entry I need. Then these js files are loaded in HTML page using `<script>` tag.

Here are dependencies I have installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "grunt": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "less-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-terser": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

Here is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MaxEmailLength' of undefined

As part of investigating this I have commented out a lot in my code and I left just this in render method in the react component:

```
<p>{ValidationHelper.MaxEmailLength}</p>
```

and this doesn't work. Seems like a simple react component will fail with just that line in the render method.

I have also tried this thing on separate different project/solution that is running typescript/react currently and I had the same issue (look like this is how it works).

As part of a different test, I have moved this

```
static readonly MaxEmailLength = 320;
```

to separate new static class then it works.

It looks like this is because ValidationHelper class uses ValidationErrors class and then ValidationErrors class uses ValidationHelper class.

In addition, I can add that this is 3.9.7 typescript version.

My question is should this work?

Comment: `this.MaxEmailLength` should be `ValidationHelper.MaxEmailLength` because the field is static.

Comment: @Clashsoft - I tried that it's same thing

Answer (score 0):

This does work for me in the TypeScript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqYgJYBMwBdEHsB2AlAphAK4hrQDeAUNNMDhGgE5HBqaMAUAdDwA5iMwAWwgAuaGGwBPANoBdAJQVoAX0prKlfAA9e7MqEgx4SVBhwAJfCF75GFTTQbpEwaI3xhkOEFOgBZMG0AUSEwRBAAGXxsAHM0AAtoAF5oAGYAJgAGAG5HaGcMNwBJCFDwkBMUDnwwiPEGRkQ4hXEqsyw8QhIyKhoaRAAzaBq6kC4QGPikgB5oLKU+-poPNCJGbGhsfAB3OAQUFxwCYlIOQYQIfAAafdMj7GDGRnYILn9EKGbY8oiFPOWGmWQxGtQqEymiWgAD5oIlPu8gr8opCEotqMt3Pg1hstrs7odzF1TmhzpcbgSOjgni9GG9itgAG4HZDI6JxRL-DE0IH9VbrTbbPbtB4nHocJhEfBcnnqTQ6PSMAzgKCUh4014ODGFVxYrw+PwfL5xZEpaAAIgACpNIPhoLwXoyUHawREuOa8tq0C43B59dhfNAGczTGzUWaAAam4CSADkZAARnaQDhYnY4QlJNAACTkEVEqw2OyIkJjdnTFS0TOCVh2N4RvIqIA). Could the error be that `ValidationHelper` isn't available in the file you're trying to use it?

FYI I'm posting this as an answer because the link is too long to fit in a comment

Comment: So each of these classes are in a separate file.In ValidationHelper  I import by import { ValidationErrors } from '../dictionary/ValidationErrors'; and in ValidationErrors I import it by import { ValidationHelper } from "../helpers/ValidationHelper";

Comment: also I'm not sure how playground works but it doesn't seem to be full example. I mean normally I build it with webpack 4.44.1 with set up that generates vendor.js and runtime.js and file per each entry I need. Then I load it by using <script> tag in the HTML page.

Comment: The playground doesn't really matter. It just demonstrates that the error doesn't lie in the code but must be due to how you're importing/exporting the module. So without any more information about that we can't help you.

Comment: as mentioned in previous comments I use import keyword to import module in each file, then these classes are used in react component. Everything is built by webpack 4.44.1 and loaded using <script> tag in HTML page. Any specific detail you want me to share? I'll try to update the main question with some extra info hope that helps.